# Forbidden You dont have permsission to access /wp-login.php on this server

Tags: wordpress

I have a website built with Wordpress. I can login with no problems but my developer cannot login.

I am in Ireland and he is in Vancouver. He is getting a forbidden message, You dont have permission to access /wp-admin.php on this server.

Incognito mode has been tried and this has not fixed the issue.

Comment: What role have you assigned to the user? Can you make sure he's assigned Administrator role and try again?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I have not given him admin access just the WP username & password. Changed .htaccess file and I have no security plugins installed. May be an issue with hosting company. Thanks John

Comment: What role does the user have? Not all users have access to the admin panel it depends on the role. The message you gave points to this as the issue.

Comment: The only issue is that the given user does not have the correct permissions in WordPress to login to admin. It's not a hosting issue. It's a permission issue. The message is in fact correct. He *is* forbidden, by the WordPress role given to him.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like his IP is blocked, either in .htaccess, by a security WordPress plugin, or by your webhost in Ireland.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your help. Yes changed .htaccess file and there are no security plugins installed. I will contact the hosting provider now. Thanks John